# The plastic number, and Padovan and Perrin-like sequences

Tags: number-theory

The ratio of $P_{n+1}$ to $P_n$ tends toward the plastic number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number) as $n$ approaches infinity for the Padovan and Perrin sequences. There are other sequences that have this property? What makes the Padovan and Perrin sequences the most fundamental of such sequences? Are they equally fundamental, whatever equally fundamental may mean in this case? What is the most fundamental way of describing the relation between these sequences?

Comment: This is not a bad question, but I expect it would not get reopened here: MathOverflow is for professional mathematicians and their PhD to discuss questions related to their research. I think it might get better reception at Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: This is not a bad question, but I expect it won't get answered here: Math Stack Exchange is for general mathematics questions, rather than deeply specialized results about exotic sequences. I think it might get a better reception at Math Overflow.

Comment: (I am not serious.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just about every sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ that satisfies a linear recurrence $a_{n+3} = a_{n+1} + a_n$ has the property that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \rho$, where $\rho$ is the unique real solution of the equation $x^3 = x + 1$. This is stated in the Wikipedia article that the OP links to.

Moreover, this is not hard to see; one way of seeing it is via generating functions. Form the power series $f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$. Then

$$\begin{array}{lll}
f(x) & = & a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n+3} x^{n+3} \\ 
 & = & a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \sum_{n \geq 0} (a_n + a_{n+1}) x^{n+3} \\ 
 & = & a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + x^3 f(x) + x^2 (f(x) - a_0)
\end{array}$$

and so after a little rearrangement we get

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0 + a_1 x + (a_2 - a_0)x^2}{1 - x^2 - x^3}$$

By the [method of partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), such a rational function may rewritten in the form

$$f(x) = \frac{A_1}{1 - \rho_1 x} + \frac{A_2}{1 - \rho_2 x} + \frac{A_3}{1 - \rho_3 x}$$

where $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are constants whose exact expression we don't need to bother with; more important is the factorization $1 - x^2 - x^3 = (1 - \rho_1 x)(1 - \rho_2 x)(1 - \rho_3 x)$ where, dividing through by $x^3$ and putting $t = 1/x$, we find $t^3 - t - 1 = (t - \rho_1)(t - \rho_2)(t - \rho_3)$. So one of the roots, say $\rho_1$, is the plastic number $\rho$, and the other two are conjugate complex numbers (of absolute value less than $1$), also mentioned in the Wikipedia article.

Anyway, the point of this calculation is that the rational function $f(x)$ can now be re-expressed as a linear combination of geometric series

$$f(x) = A_1 \sum_{n \geq 0} \rho^n x^n + A_2 \sum_{n \geq 0} \rho_2^n x^n + A_3 \sum_{n \geq 0} \rho_3^n x^n$$

which by matching coefficients, gives us a reasonably explicit expression for $a_n$:

$$a_n = A_1 \rho^n + A_2 \rho_2^n + A_3 \rho_3^n$$

Because $|\rho_2| = |\rho_3| < 1$ and $|\rho| > 1$, it is clear that as $n$ approaches infinity, the dominant term is $A_1 \rho^n$ (*provided* that $A_1$ doesn't vanish!); the other terms converge to $0$. And so asymptotically, $a_n \approx A_1 \rho^n$. Similarly,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A_1 \rho^{n+1}}{A_1 \rho^n} = \rho$$

by an elementary manipulation, and this proves the claim.

As for the other questions, I have no way of evaluating which of various sequences satisfying this recurrence is to be considered "most fundamental", except perhaps on grounds of "simplicity". For example, one of those sequences (the Padovan sequence, is it?) gives the reasonably simple-looking $f(x) = \frac{1 + x}{1 - x^2 - x^3}$. But what the analysis above shows is that all such sequences are (complex) linear combinations of the three sequences $\rho^n$, $\rho_2^n$, $\rho_3^n$ -- and so perhaps those should be considered the most fundamental (again, on grounds of simplicity).

Comment: In particular, provided that $a_0, a_1, a_2$ are positive integers, the sequence $a_n$ is monotonically increasing (perhaps after waiting a few terms), and so again by asymptotic considerations, the $A_1$ must be non-vanishing in that case. I think the same could be said if $a_0, a_1, a_2$ are natural numbers and not all are zero.

Comment: One could ask, among all the sequences satisfying $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$, what makes the Fibonacci sequence so special?

Comment: Would this mean that all such sequences would share the same inflation matrix? In this case [010,001,110]? I am drawing this terminology from an article of Freeman Dyson https://www.msri.org/realvideo/ln/msri/2002/rmt/dyson/1/index.html

Comment: Without watching the video, I if the inflation matrix for this case takes each triplet $(a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2})^T$ to $(a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, a_{n+3})^T$, then yes. (The $T$ here stands for transpose, meaning we are treating these triplets as column vectors.) This is really nothing but a restatement of the linear recurrence: the equations $a_{n+1} = 0 a_n + 1 a_{n+1} + 0 a_{n+2}$ and $a_{n+2} = 0 a_n + 0 a_{n+1} + 1 a_{n+2}$ making up the first two rows of the matrix are tautologies, and the last row is read off the linear recurrence $a_{n+3} = 1 a_n + 1 a_{n+1} + 0 a_{n+2}$.

Comment: What is the relation between the sequence of the powers of the inflation matrix mentioned above [010,001,110] and the sequence of the powers of the plastic number?

Comment: Notice that if you take the Vandermonde matrix $A$ given by $a_{ij} = \rho_j^{i-1}$, then each column vector (with entries $1, \rho_j, \rho_j^2$) is an eigenvector of the inflation matrix $M$ with eigenvalue $\rho_j$. This tells you immediately that $M A = A D$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\rho_i$. Thus $M = A D A^{-1}$ and $M^n = A D^n A^{-1}$. This should answer your question. By the way: if my answer above and my additional comments were useful to you, please consider accepting my answer (there's a check mark button), as this is the custom for stackexchange sites.

Comment: How would you understand this phrase of Hans van der Laan (co-discoverer of the Plastic number and its aesthetic/architectonic significance:" the Plastic Number is the ideal ratio of the geometric scale for spatial objects" (See this, for me, fascinating article http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2001-02-1-056.pdf). Is this founded on something or should it be regarded as uninteresting mysticism.

Comment: Although I've only taken a quick look at it, the article you linked to is interesting as mathematics. As far as aesthetics are concerned, I wouldn't want to say these speculations are uninteresting, but it's a bit difficult for me to evaluate. Part of my thinks that some of the literature on the golden ratio might be a bit overblown (e.g. its alleged manifestations in Hellenistic art and architecture), but on the other hand it's a fact that the golden ratio and the Fibonacci numbers can be found in nature (as in sunflowers and pine cones), and some of this is scientifically explicable. (cont.)

Comment: And the mathematical significance of the golden ratio is also well explored. So it would be very interesting to me if manifestations of the plastic number (or the Padovan sequence, etc.) appear in nature. I have not looked at the articles of van der Laan or Padovan specifically, but from what I can glean some of it seems pretty speculative (nothing wrong with that, just that it's hard for me to evaluate).

Comment: If Pn/Pn-1 converges on the Plastic Number as n approaches infinity, it ought to diverge as n approaches negative infinity.  The sign of these can be paired with the Perrin and Padovan numbers of positive index.  It is a pattern in which you will never get more than two negative or positive numbers in a row, and yet is aperiodic with regard to sign. Compare with Negative indexed Fibonacci numbers. Does this tell you something about the way in which the Plastic number is associated with a quasicrystal? The Freeman Dyson .pdf speaks about all PV numbers as being associated with a quasicrystal.

Comment: This looks very interesting, but I am unable to load the video for some reason, and from where I stand the .pdf can only be clicked on one page at a time, which makes it awkward to read. What is meant by a "PV number"?

Comment: Try this link:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38370878/dyson%20another%20lecture%20on%20rh%20and%20qcs.pdf

Comment: A PV Number is a Pisot number. The article of Dyson speaks of some of the same matters that he treats in the essay "Birds and Frogs" http://www.ams.org/notices/200902/rtx090200212p.pdf but the first essay speaks of the Plastic Number, tying it in.

Comment: Thanks for that download, and thanks for the reminder (PV stands for Pisot–Vijayaraghavan, then). I don't think I can just dash off a reply, as I am not yet familiar with the Bombieri-Taylor theorem and how it might relate to your question. (And it's definitely getting into territory outside my own research preoccupations.) So I'd need some time to think about this.

Comment: Another thing to think about: What does the Plastic quasicrystal (which has to to with measuring spatial (three-dimensional) objects (all geometry has to do with the three dimensions, even when measuring just in one dimension) have to do with the icosahedral symmetry which is the root of every quasicrystal in three dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are interested in the significance of the Padovan and Perrin sequences and how they are related to each other.

A distinguishing feature of the Padovan sequence is that it is a whorled triangle that grows as this sequence that will form a complete, closed mosaic that covers the plane, much as the Fibonacci mosaic is a whorled square. Moreover, the spiral that is composed of circular arcs that circumscribe the triangles, approximates a logarithmic spiral with a flair coefficient of $b=3\text{ln}p/\pi$, where $p$ is the plastic constant. Again, there is a parallel between the Fibonacci and Padovan sequences. The figure below shows the mosaic and Padovan spiral.

The Perrin number apparently has some significance in graph theory, but that is beyond my ken. You can get started on that here: [Perrin Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrin_number#Notes).

Now, as pointed out elsewhere on this page, almost every sequence $P(n≥0)$ that satisfies a linear recurrence $P_{n+3}=P_{n+1}+P_n$ has the property that $$\lim_{n→∞}\frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n}=p$$

All such sequences can be found analytically from the Binet-like formula
$$P(n)=ap^n+bq^n+cr^n$$
where $p, q \text{ and } r$ are the roots of the equation
$$x^3=x+1$$
and the constants $a, b \text{ and } c$ are to be determine from the initial conditions, i.e., $[P(0),P(1),P(2)]$. Thus, $a, b \text{ and } c$ can be found from the linear equations

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b+c=P(0) \\ 
ap+bq+cr=P(1) \\ 
ap^2+bq^2+cr^2=P(2)
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

with the solution

$$\begin{array}{l}a = \frac{{ - P\left( 2 \right) + P\left( 1 \right)\left( {q + r} \right) - P\left( 0 \right)qr}}{{\left( {p - q} \right)\left( {p - r} \right)}}\\b = \frac{{P\left( 1 \right)p - P\left( 2 \right) - P\left( 0 \right)pr + P\left( 1 \right)r}}{{\left( { - p + q} \right)\left( {q - r} \right)}}\\c = {b^*}\end{array}$$

Now, since $b$ and $c$ are complex conjugates, as are $q$ and $r$, we can write

$$P(n)=ap^n+2\mathfrak{Re}\{bq^n\}$$

which shows that $P(n)$ is always real. As a side note, I have shown (as probably have many others) that $P(n)=\text{Round}(ap^n)$ for the Padovan sequence, at least. (I haven't really tried it on any others.)

So this little discussion shows how the Padovan and Perrin sequences are related. It's also worth noting that for the Perrin sequence $a=b=c=1$. And now the Padovan mosaic and spiral...
[image: Whorled Padovan mosaic and spiral]